# Porque No me toma los valores en metodo $_POST | print_r() expects at most 2 parameters...on line 5

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5, phpmyadmin

```
    $habitacion=$_POST['habitacion'];
    $estado=$_POST['estado'];
    $personas=$_POST['personas'];

    print_r($habitacion,$estado,$personas);

            $query="SELECT * FROM habitacion WHERE hab_id='$habitacion'";
            $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);

            if($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                            $sql="UPDATE habitacion SET hab_estado='".$estado."', hab_personas=".$personas." WHERE hab_id = ".$habitacion.")";
                            $res1=$conexion->query($sql);
                }
```

-------------------------------------HTML--------------------------------

```
<form action="Admin_FuncionalCambiarEstadoHabitacion.php" method="POST" class="needs-validation">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                        <label for="habitacion">N° De Habitacion</label>
                        <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="habitacion" name="habitacion" required>
                          <option>Seleccione</option>
                          <?php include ('Admin_NumeroDeHabitacion.php'); ?>
                          </select>
                      </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                      <label for="estado">Estado De La Habitacion</label>
                      <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="estado" name="estado" required>
                          <option>Seleccione</option>
                          <option value="Disponible">Disponible</option>
                          <option value="Ocupado">Reservado</option>
                          <option value="Mantenimiento">En Mantenimiento</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                      <label for="personas">Numero De Personas</label>
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="personas" name="personas" placeholder="Numero De Personas" required>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback" style="width: 100%;">
                          Your Number is required.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <button class="col-md-4 btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Registrar</button>
              </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás usando la funciín `print_r()` con tres parámetros cuando solo admite 2:

Estas son las especificaciones:

```
mixed print_r ( mixed $expression [, bool $return = false ] )
```

1. Expresión: La expresión a ser impresa.
2. Return: Si desea capturar la salida de print_r(), use el parámetro
   return. Cuando el parámetro es establecido a TRUE, print_r()
   devolverá la información en lugar de imprimirla.

Si lo que quieres es ver la variable `$_POST` haz lo siguiente:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Esto imprimirá el array entero.

[Aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php) tienes más información sobre la función.